# UserInformationRecoveryService for WSO2 Identity Server not available in http

Tags: soap, wsdl, wso2-identity-server

Listing Admin services via OSGI Console of WSO2 Identity Server (5.1.0) lists that the service is available only on https as shown below:

55. UserInformationRecoveryService, UserInformationRecoveryService, https://localhost:9443/services/UserInformationRecoveryService/

In a scenario where SSL is terminated on a front-end device like Load balancer, the destination url results to be a http only url. Invoking any related operation (like getCaptcha()) ends up in error.

EPR error as below:

*The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) **http**://hostname:9763/services/UserInformationRecoveryService.UserInformationRecoveryServiceHttpsSoap12Endpoint*

**To Summarize**

Service is available only on https via an OOTB jar but due to SSL termination  the location url ends up on http while an operation is being invoked.

Any pointers on how to handle such issue in a SSL termination scenario would be of great help..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Open [Product_Home]/repository/conf/carbon.xml file and uncomment below element.

`<HttpAdminServices>*</HttpAdminServices>`

Uncommenting above parameter would expose all AdminServices in HTTP transport. With HTTP transport your credentials and data routed in public channels are vulnerable to attacks.

Comment: The above suggested element is already uncommented and we could see other services listed out for both http and https protocols. For example we are actively using "RemoteUserStoreManager Service" as it is available in http also - Listed below  via listAdminService using osgiConsole.
8. RemoteUserStoreManagerService, RemoteUserStoreManagerService, https://localhost:9443/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService/ http://localhost:9763/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService/